# use git to see how to use the lib

Tags: git, github

Can you tell me what do you do when you need to see how others use a specific library?

I'm a n00b when is about the use of git, but I got a question in my mind. Is it possible to see how others use a specific open source library in github or any repository service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can google for the library or a often-used function in that library and hope to find sourcecode of programs using it.

Git/Github doesn't really help you in doing so.